# Include ".framework" file to cocoapods

Tags: ios, xcode, frameworks, cocoapods

I'm trying to add "Custom.framework" to my pod (cocoapods).
And I'm a bit stuck with pod spec setup. I've done following:

```
s.resources = ['Resources/Custom.framework']
s.preserve_paths = "Resources/Custom.framework"
s.frameworks  = "UIKit", "Custom"
```

But in project where I'm using this pod, I'm getting error

```
<Custom/Custom.h> not found
```

or something similar.

I'm stuck already for a few hours and I can't find answer to my question in google.

BR, Pavlo.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

What you want is the [`vendored_frameworks`](http://guides.cocoapods.org/syntax/podspec.html#vendored_frameworks) attribute. In your case it looks like you'd want to use it like this:

```
s.vendored_frameworks = 'Resources/Custom.framework'
```

This automatically deals with preserving the path and linking the framework itself so you don't need either of those attributes for your custom framework.

Comment: I tried putting my framework inside a Resources folder, where the podspec file is, and then included this line in the podspec: s.vendored_frameworks = 'Resources/Custom.framework'.  However, that did not work. What DID work for me, was placing my Custom.framework in the same place as the podspec file is, and then inserted this line in the podspec instead: s.vendored_frameworks = 'Custom.framework' .   After 'pod install' (don't forget this part), a new group called 'Frameworks' was generated automatically under my pod directory, and I had no more header file missing errors from the framework.

Answer (score 1):

Using `vendored_frameworks` did the inclusion as @Keith said. But the addition to his answer is that I added the custom framework as a '**Do Not Embed**' option. and the pod was able to link it and provide it to the using Application.

[image: How the framework is embedded]

You can also provide more frameworks. The following line includes `Custom. framework` nad `Custom2.framework` frameworks and any Xcode framework `.xcframework`

`s.vendored_frameworks = 'YourOwnFrameworksFolder/Custom.framework' , 'YourOwnFrameworksFolder/Custom2.framework', 'YourOwnFrameworksFolder/**.xcframework'`

Also, if your Custom.framework needs another framework to work successfully, I think you will need to provide it also in the `vendored_frameworks` but you don't need to embed it in your pod framework project as the pod project itself does not use it directly.

So for example, if `Custom.framework` needs `CustomDependency.framework`, the `vendored_frameworks` will be :

`s.vendored_frameworks = 'YourOwnFrameworksFolder/Custom.framework' , 'YourOwnFrameworksFolder/CustomDependency.framework'`