# Distribute compiled .framework with cocoapods

Tags: ios, cocoapods, ios-frameworks

I'm working on an iOS app with my team and I would like to move a chunk of code in a precompiled framework in order to reduce compile time. I created a framework with the source files, uploaded it on a git repo and distributed it to the rest of my team with cocoapods.

But instead of having a .framework folder with only headers, I get .h et .m files. Here is my pod hierarchy as found in the including project.

[image]

I browsed the other pods used in my app and found some having the hierarchy I'm looking for:

[image]

Is there an option to change in the .podspec file in order to distribute the compiled version of the framework ?

Here is a snapshot of my .podspec file :

```
Pod::Spec.new do |s|

  s.platform     = :ios, "9.0"
  s.source       = { :git => "URL" }

  s.source_files  = "MessengerPaintCode", "MessengerPainCode/**/*.{h}"

end
```

My questions are :

- Is the pod presented in the second image a precompiled pod ?
- How to distribute the compiled version of my framework in order to avoid compiling it each time I compile the app including it ?

Comment: Your question is kinda hard to understand...if you want to use pod with compiled framework, just simply include it in the folder and use `vendored_framework`

Comment: @Tj3n That's what I saw on this [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26950423/include-framework-file-to-cocoapods), but I don't know how to automatically get the .framework folder path since it change each time I build, due to the change of the folder name in which it is built in DerivedData.

Comment: You will need to add some build script to move the files from your DerivedData to other folder

Comment: Did you find answer to this? I am trying to do the same. I would like to distribute my cocoa pod with just the framework. For example, https://github.com/Instabug/Instabug-iOS distributes just the framework.

Comment: use `spec.source = { :http => 'http://dev.wechatapp.com/download/sdk/WeChat_SDK_iOS_en.zip' }`  https://guides.cocoapods.org/syntax/podspec.html#source

Answer (score 1):

You can use `vendored_frameworks` for this:

```
s.subspec 'MyLib' do |mylib|
  mylib.source_files = 'MyLib/Classes/**/*'
  mylib.vendored_frameworks = 'MyLib/Frameworks/closed-source.framework'
end
```